# two html select conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html select element that the second one is disabled at first and only become enable if user choose one option from first select. consider we have 2 options in first select -> a , b  if user choose a : in the second select options should be : a1,a2 if user choose b : in the second select options should be : b1,b2 ...  I dont know what am i doing wrong that these two select options have conflict with each other !!!

```
<select id="main-category" required>
    <option disabled selected> choose one option </option>
    <option value="a"> a </option>
    <option value="b"> b </option>  
</select>
<select id="sub-category" required disabled> </select>
<!-- empty select -->
<script>
    document.getElementById("main-category").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('sub-category').disabled = false;
        var opt0 = document.createElement('option');
        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
        if (this.value == 'a') {
             //first remove all previous options then add new ones
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            opt0.value = "a1";
            opt0.innerHTML = "a1";
            opt1.value = "a2";
            opt1.innerHTML = "a2";
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt0);
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt1);
        } else if (this.value == 'b') {
            //first remove all previous options then add new ones
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0]) { //check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            opt0.value = "b1";
            opt0.innerHTML = "b1";
            opt1.value = "b2";
            opt1.innerHTML = "b2";
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt0);
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt1);
        }
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is clear out the previous entries in the second drop down every time a selection is made in the first one.

```html
<select id="main-category" required>
    <option disabled selected> choose one option </option>
    <option value="a"> a </option>
    <option value="b"> b </option>  
</select>
<select id="sub-category" required disabled> </select>
<!-- empty select -->
<script>
    document.getElementById("main-category").onchange = function() {
       
       // Clear out the second list before adding new items to it
       document.getElementById('sub-category').innerHTML = "";
       // *******************************************************
    
        document.getElementById('sub-category').disabled = false;
        var opt0 = document.createElement('option');
        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
        if (this.value == 'a') {
             //first remove all previous options then add new ones
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            opt0.value = "a1";
            opt0.innerHTML = "a1";
            opt1.value = "a2";
            opt1.innerHTML = "a2";
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt0);
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt1);
        } else if (this.value == 'b') {
            //first remove all previous options then add new ones
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0]) { //check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            if (document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1]) {//check if there is a option then remove it
                var opt = document.getElementById('sub-category').getElementsByTagName('option')[1];
                document.getElementById('sub-category').removeChild(opt);
            }
            opt0.value = "b1";
            opt0.innerHTML = "b1";
            opt1.value = "b2";
            opt1.innerHTML = "b2";
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt0);
            document.getElementById('sub-category').appendChild(opt1);
        }
    };

</script>
```

But, beyond that, your code needs to be cleaned up quite a bit because you shouldn't be scanning the document for the element you want to work with over and over again when you've already found it before. That's extremely wasteful.

Also, `.innerHTML` is for passing strings that contain HTML so that the HTML parser can parse the string and update the DOM accordingly. You are just setting plain strings with no HTML in them, so you should be using `.textContent` instead, which doesn't invoke the HTML parser and is more efficient.

Next (just FYI), if you want the value of an `option` to be the same as the text that is displayed to the user, you don't need to set a `value` for that `option`. The `value` is the contents of the `option` element by default.

Really, the entire operation can be made so much simpler by simply making new options in list2 based on the first letter of the option chosen in list1.

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll be working with just once:
var list1 = document.getElementById("main-category");
var list2 = document.getElementById('sub-category');

list1.onchange = function() {

  list2.disabled = false;
  
  var newHTML = "";  // A string that will contain the new HTML for the second list
  
  // Loop the amount of times we find <option> elements in list one, but start
  // at the second one to account for the first one, which isn't really a true choice
  for(var i = 1; i < list1.querySelectorAll("option").length; i++){
    // Build up a string that the new option should be made from using the 
    // first character from the option found in list 1
    newHTML += '<option>' + list1.value.substr(0,1) + i + '</option>';
  }
  
  // By setting a new value for .innerHTML, the old values get thrown out.
  list2.innerHTML = newHTML;
};
```

```html
<select id="main-category" required>
    <option disabled selected> choose one option </option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>  
</select>
<select id="sub-category" required disabled> </select>
```

Comment: huge tnx brother ... but I have a little question ... you said : "if you want the value of an option to be the same as the text that is displayed to the user, you don't need to set a value for that option. The value is the contents of the option element by default."

Comment: @AhmadReza Yes. That is what I said. What's your question?

Comment: huge tnx brother ... but I have a little question ... you said : "if you want the value of an option to be the same as the text that is displayed to the user, you don't need to set a value for that option. The value is the contents of the option element by default." if I use .textContent (not the .innerHTML) to change the text for user , will the value of option become same as contents of the option ? or if I use  .textContent I have to set the value attribute manually ?

Comment: @AhmadReza If you use `.textContent` to change the contents of the `<option>` element(s), then that text will also be the value of thse corresponding `<option>` element(s). The only time you need to specify a `value` is when you want the text to show one thing to the user, but the underlying value to be recorded as something else.